# Has anyone get result from SQL Server database with Docker apache/airflow:2.1.0

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

i'm trying to get data from Microsoft SQL Server by Airflow
I created a DAG like that :

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, get_current_context, task
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depend_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}


def start(**kwargs):
    print("Hey!")


def extract(**kwargs):
    conn = MsSqlHook.get_connection(conn_id="sqlconnection_reader")
    hook = conn.get_hook()
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql="SELECT top 5 * FROM [dbo].[1_del_ListPO]")
    print(df)


with DAG(
    'test_get_data_mssqlhook',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='ETL DAG MSSQL',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['mssql'],
) as dag:
    start_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='start',
        python_callable=start,
    )

    extract_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='extract',
        python_callable=extract,
    )

    start_task >> extract_task
```

I got error on Airflow
[image: error in Airflow Web UI]

List providers that I installed in airflow here:
[image: list of providers in cli]

And this is my configuration of connection
[image: view of connection in Airflow Web UI]

Comment: What Airflow version and executor do you use?

Comment: Thanks to your question, my problem has been solved. i find out that i have not installed provider on Celery Executor server. I installed provider packages on Celery server then refesh airflow => the error has not been occur.